# Is there a way to select elements of an array every second?

Tags: javascript, web-deployment

What I'm trying to achieve is to loop and toggle a class on every individual div every second.

Below is the code to create 4 divs with colour from an array.

```
const container = document.querySelector(".container");
const colors = ["#FDB10B", "#FE8535", "#FD292F", "#B20000"];
const ball = container.querySelectorAll("div");

for (let i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
    const balls = document.createElement("div");
    balls.style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
    container.appendChild(balls);
}
```

Now I want to loop through the containers element every second and Google a class on the elements.

I tried using the `setInterval()` method

Comment: Add every `ball` to a new array and loop every second with `setInterval` through this new array.

Comment: I tried that but its selecting all the elements but not the children element

Comment: Could you show how you tried with setInterval so we could see what may go  wrong ?

Comment: `... and Google a class on the elements.` - Can you explain this part? It's unclear what you want to do with the elements in the array. When you say "Google" do you mean "search"? Do you want to add a class to them? Check if they already have it? Do something if they have a certain class?

Answer (score 0):

I've added a class "ball" you could as well refer to element by container > div, but easier to understand this way.

```js
const container = document.querySelector(".container");
const colors = ["#FDB10B", "#FE8535", "#FD292F", "#B20000"];
const ball = container.querySelectorAll("div");

for (let i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
  const balls = document.createElement("div");
  balls.style.backgroundColor = colors[i];
  balls.classList.add('ball');
  container.appendChild(balls);
}


setInterval(function() {
  toggle();
}, 1000)

function toggle() {
  const tog = document.querySelector('.class-to-toggle');
  if (tog) {
    tog.classList.remove('class-to-toggle');
    const nextTog = tog.nextElementSibling;
    if (nextTog) {
      nextTog.classList.add('class-to-toggle');
    } else {
      document.querySelector('.ball').classList.add('class-to-toggle');
    }
  } else {
    document.querySelector('.ball').classList.add('class-to-toggle');
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
</div>
```

if you inspect in dev tools you'll see class changed

Answer (score 0):

Here is another example of the way you could do this.

Your question lacks some details about what you need to do so the example is quite generic.

```js
const container = document.querySelector(".container");
const colors = ["#FDB10B", "#FE8535", "#FD292F", "#B20000"];

colors.forEach(color => {
  const ball = document.createElement("div");
  ball.classList.add("ball");
  
  // Added some stylnig value for the example
  ball.style.width = "20px";
  ball.style.height = "20px";
  
  ball.style.backgroundColor = color;
  container.appendChild(ball);
});

const balls = container.querySelectorAll(".ball");
let cursor = 0;

const int_id = setInterval(selectNextBall, 1000);

function selectNextBall() {
  const selectedBall = balls[cursor];

  // I do this just to illustrate the example, 
  // could be anything you need to do with your ball.
  for (const ball of balls) {
    ball.style.border = ball === selectedBall ? "1px solid black" : "none";
  }
  
  // for an endless loop
  cursor = cursor === balls.length - 1 ? 0 : cursor + 1;

  // Or if the loop need to iterate just once
  /*
  if (cursor === balls.length - 1) {
    clearInterval(int_id);
  }
  cursor++
  */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

</div>
```